# Icmp subnet address request

Tags: c++, icmp, subnet

I'm trying to understand how i can get a subnet address using ICMP. In the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Address_mask_request) (other sources as well), there is a message example, but all I was able to find has nothing to do with this message.

Tried to use IcmpSendEcho (from [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx)), but it seemed to me, that it performs only ping function, correct me if i'm wrong.

Can you give me some code example (c/c++), or may be links?

Edit:

The code I used:

```
int __cdecl main()  {

// Declare and initialize variables

HANDLE hIcmpFile;
unsigned long ipaddr = INADDR_NONE;
DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
char SendData[12] = "Data Buffer";
LPVOID ReplyBuffer = NULL;
DWORD ReplySize = 0;
ipaddr = inet_addr("217.71.130.248");
hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
if (hIcmpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("\tUnable to open handle.\n");
    printf("IcmpCreatefile returned error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

ReplySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData);
ReplyBuffer = (VOID*)malloc(ReplySize);
if (ReplyBuffer == NULL) {
    printf("\tUnable to allocate memory\n");
    return 1;
}

dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, ipaddr, SendData, sizeof(SendData),
    NULL, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 1000);
if (dwRetVal != 0) {
    PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY)ReplyBuffer;
    struct in_addr ReplyAddr;
    ReplyAddr.S_un.S_addr = pEchoReply->Address;
    printf("\tSent icmp message to %s\n", "217.71.130.248");
    printf("\tReceived %ld icmp message response\n", dwRetVal);
    printf("\tInformation from this response:\n");

    printf("\t  Received from %s\n", inet_ntoa(ReplyAddr));
    printf("\t  Status = %ld\n",
        pEchoReply->Status);
    printf("\t  Roundtrip time = %ld milliseconds\n",
        pEchoReply->RoundTripTime);
}
else {
    printf("\tCall to IcmpSendEcho failed.\n");
    printf("\tIcmpSendEcho returned error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

}

I get an answer from the IP, that works alright. But I need to get subnet address and I'm stuck at it

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ECHO` (aka ping) is a specific type of ICMP request.  ICMP supports other types of messages, but `IcmpSendEcho()` can only send `ECHO` requests and receive `ECHO` replies, hence its name.  So you cannot use it to send an `ADDRESS MASK` request to your router to get the subnet address.

Microsoft does not have an API to send general-purpose ICMP requests. You would have to use the standard socket API (WinSock on Windows) to create a socket with a type of `SOCK_RAW` and a protocol of `IPPROTO_ICMP` (as ICMP runs on top of IP but is separate from TCP/UDP), then you can manually construct and send your own ICMP requests, and then read and parse the ICMP replies.  Do be aware that `SOCK_RAW` requires admin rights on most platforms, including Windows.

That being said, you **do not** need to resort to ICMP to get your machine's subnet address.  The OS already knows it, and there are OS-specific APIs available to get that information, such as `GetAdaptersInfo()` and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` on Windows, and `getifaddrs()` on POSIX systems.